# Drawing abstract canvas

Tags: language-agnostic, drawing, transform, zooming

I'm planning to write a diagram editor-style application, where you organize objects on a canvas. This application will need to support setting viewport, zooming, cropping and a lot of other standard features of such a graph style application. I'm looking for toolkits or frameworks which could supports drawing in a standard mathematical coordinate space (0,0 as center point, extendable in all directions), and will scale, crop and zoom this according to (user) commands. Language doesn't really matter, but the more geared it is towards standard GUI applications the better. I would namely like to be able to reuse standard controls and buttons on the canvas if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Qt is your friend here. Offers what you need, is multiplatform, quite well-designed and there are bindings for several languages.

Comment: Great! Can't believe I never noticed that QT supports that.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, anything mid-level like C++ with toolboxes - QT, GTK, Windows API etc is horrible for such a work. Not that they can't do it, just that there's 15 lines of obscure code per each simple operation - they are simply not very efficient and more geared towards creating fixed GUI than arbitrary graphics.

This sounds like a good work for Flash, optionally something on top of SVG, maybe even a web app in Javascript.